# Random values in tensorflow

Tags: random, tensorflow

I want to generate random numbers within an activation function such that every time the activation function is called a random number is generated. I tried with random.uniform and with tf.random_uniform but it only generates a single random value when it's compiled and it doesn't change anymore. How can I make it update every time?

Funny fact:
When I create a variable using tf.Variable(random.uniform(1,2)) every time the function it's called the value is slightly larger, for instance:

```
1.22069513798
1.22072458267
1.22075247765
1.22077202797
```

Edit:
The function is very simple
Function:

```
def activation(tensor):
    alpha = tf.Variable(random.uniform(1,2))
    return alpha*tensor,alpha
```

I will omit all the lines in the neural network, but I simply call it as:

```
act,alpha = activation(dense_layer+bias)
```

I later get the value by simply:

```
[ts,c,alph]=sess.run([train_step,cost,alpha], feed_dict={xi: x_raw, yi: y_raw})
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hard to tell without source code, but maybe you are initializing your variable with that random value and reusing same value?

Another possibility:

[image]

Comment: I added the code of my last attempt. I don't think what's depicted in the figure you posted it's happening because I'm printing thousands of iterations that gave me the same random value : )

Comment: yes, you are saving your random variable into variable alpha during initialization. If you want to reinitialize with new random value, you can do `sess.run(alpha.initializer)`